# If having a beard is potentially dangerous to life, should a Jew shave it off?

Tags: pikuachnefesh-danger-life, beard

There are reports that men with beards may have problems using face masks effectively or getting hooked up to a ventilator correctly. Given the danger posed by the COVID-19 virus, should Jewish men shave their beards before they fall ill?

Comment: If they need a ventilator I assume the hospital would shave their beard...?

Comment: There are still ways to shave a beard without having to use a razor. There are also ways to cut a beard sufficiently close to allow a ventilator to work. For example, I am able to use a CPAP even with my beard.

Comment: @sabbahillel That is good to know.

Comment: Due to the need to have tight fitting gas masks, during the Gulf war Israeli men shaved off their beards.  Israeli newspapers showed photos of some newly shorn rabbis.

Answer (score 4):

Anesthesiologist here: Beards aren't a problem for a ventilator.
They make my job harder when I have to mask ventilate someone before putting in a breathing tube, but since we've stopped mask ventilating covid-19 patients, it doesn't matter.

A beard will make it impossible for a traditional N95 respirator to fit properly, which will preclude you from protecting yourself (or other people) from breathing in the virus.

A year ago, I'd recommend buying a PAPR (Powered Air Purifying Respirator) which is the space hood you've seen, and which works just as well as an N95 but would let you keep the beard. Now that you can't find one available to buy, if you want to wear an N95 respirator mask properly, trim the beard.

Health care facilities fit test all employees yearly to make sure we can wear N95 respirator masks properly.

I have colleagues who have trimmed beards because,  while in years past we could avoid having them work with patients with things like tuberculosis, this year, everyone is at risk of covid-19.

(This doesn't answer the question, but does clarify that a beard isn't a problem at all for being on a ventilator. The goal, of course, is to avoid needing the ventilator in the first place...)

Comment: Thank you, it's good to hear from a medical professional. Just to clarify, when you say "trim" for an N95, does that just mean to cut fairly short (1/8 - 1/4 inch), not to shave smooth?

Comment: The short answer is it depends on your face and the brand of mask. That is why the occupational health department at any hospital fit tests the staff. It is certainly possible to have 1/8 inch of hair and pass a fit test. The test involves putting a giant hood over your head and then they spray saccharine in. If you are unable to smell the saccharine, then your mask is fitting properly.

Answer (score 1):

This question is "consult your Rabbi" question.
That being said,

During six-days war, soldiers were asked to shave their beards so gas-masks will fit better.
[Rabbi Shlomo Goren](https://www.inn.co.il/News/News.aspx/336825) resisted that ,and it was concluded that every soldier will decide for himself.

(EDIT: He resisted because he thought that damage of demoralization is grater then the risk of possible gas attack)

I also found [somebody](https://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?cat_id=4&topic_id=2902705&forum_id=771) who says that during the gulf wars many people and rabbis shaved their beards, also hinted by Rabbi Yona Mtzger [here](https://www.srugim.co.il/10803-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%92%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%91%D7%99%D7%98%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%93%D7%90%D7%92-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9B-%D7%9C%D7%91).

Comment: The rabbis in my yeshiva shaved off their beards during the Gulf War, except for the rosh yeshiva who was (and is) important enough a person to receive a mask for bearded men.

Comment: Which page does Rabbi goren write this its like a 30 page document??

Comment: @AviM look for "אני הודעתי שאינני מסכים לזה בשום פנים ואופן"

Comment: On what page on the PDF?

Comment: @AviM Not on PDF, it's quoted on the article's text.

Comment: I understand but there is an attached pdf of Rabbi Gorens notes - will I find it in there as well?

Comment: @AviM pages 14-15

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Shlomo Aviner in his new pamphlet *Keser Yitnu Lecha* (COVID-19 in Haskafa and Halacha) was asked as to whether a paramedic who has an order from his employer to shave his beard should do so in order to be able to continue his work. He ruled that he must as a protocol of "*Venishmartem*".

https://7d4ab068-0603-408d-89df-fac4580e17c4.filesusr.com/ugd/8b9b1c_ed8c6fc8417b4fbdb5a59494f324fc0e.pdf